# Connecting from php application to gearman server over ssl

Tags: php, gearman

I am trying to encrypt the connection from an application running on php 5.6.40 to gearman server(version 1.1.12). I have started gearman server enabling ssl and passed the ca file, certificate and key as arguments.

```
gearmand -d --ssl --ssl-ca-file=ca.crt --ssl-certificate=gearman.crt --ssl-key=gearman.key
```

Where I am stuck now is to get my php client use ssl. I am using GearmanClient class that comes with php's gearman extension and I could not figure out a way to achieve this.

```
 $gearmanClient = new GearmanClient();
 $gearmanClient->addServer('server ip', 4730);
 $result = $gearmanClient->doHighBackground('job-type', 'workload');
```

The code above works but the job-type and workload are sent un-encrypted to gearman server. If it is not possible with php's gearman extension, does anybody know if we can use socket functions to achieve this? I have gone through a lot of threads related to this, but could not find a proper answer. Apologies if this has been already answered.

Comment: Hi, your question seems to be lacking some code or anything that a potential answerer could use to help you out. Could you insert a snippet of code to better understand your question? Thanks!

Comment: @Eugenio I have updated the question with some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL support in gearmand works just fine. I have been using it in a production environment for ~3 years now. The issue mentioned in another answer is still open because that issue is really about making improvements to the documentation, and that wishlist item is unresolved.

Getting SSL support in the PHP extension is possible, but it will require patching and compiling the code yourself. The current version of the PHP extension can be found at https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman, but that is for PHP 7.x.

The Gearman PECL extension for older versions of PHP (< 7.x) is no longer maintained, as far as I know, but you can download the latest version at https://github.com/hjr3/pecl-gearman and apply the patch at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67623. It works. My workplace used that in production for about a year before moving to PHP 7.x.

If you are using PHP 7+, I recently opened a PR for adding SSL support at https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/pull/72. You should also read the issue thread at https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/issues/43 for some caveats.

In either case, you also need a `libgearman.so` from gearmand 1.1.19 or newer that was compiled with `--enable-ssl` and has support for the `setSSL()` API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps a lot.

Comment: Gearmand 1.1.19 was recently released with `setSSL()` support in `libgearman.so`. Updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

I hesitated to answer the question previously because it is related to PHP.

Actually `gearmand` supports SSL connection properly. The issue mentioned by @emix is still opened because there is no ssl tests for `gearmand` itself in [repository](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand).

Perl Implementation of `gearmand` [Client/Worker](https://github.com/p-alik/perl-Gearman) supports SSL connection and contains [ssl tests](https://github.com/p-alik/perl-Gearman/blob/master/t/18-ssl.t) for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did see the perl implementation you mentioned. Doesn't look like the PHP implementation has the flag like use_ssl.

Comment: Meanwhile @ed-sabol answered your question elaborately.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is alleged to be **not** working. [This was posted as a bug long time ago](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/issues/207) and the issue is still considered open. The official extension seems dead as well: last release was more than 6 years ago.

If I were in your shoes I'd switch to something more stable with better community support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Noticed that the official extension has not been maintained for long. Do you have any suggestion for something more stable? Also, the thread that you shared in your answer indicates more of a certificate issue where the error could occur when the CN is same for ca and server certs. With the Gearman client that I use, there is no option to even ask the server to use ssl.

Comment: Depends upon one’s use case I guess. Maybe something simple as Redis’ pub/sub would do. Or maybe use something more sophisticated like RabbitMq. Back to the case, thread says running with the ssl works fine, albeit crashing when trying to connect using a secure connection. I would never use any software that lacks basic security. Why you need an encrypted connection though? Are you not going to use this locally, but through the web? Consider making a SSH tunnel then. Are you willing to upvote my answer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Upvoted your answer. The reason we need encrypted connection is a company policy though it is internal traffic. Don't think we will have the opportunity to use a different queing system though. SSH tunnelling could be an option. I hoped there would be a straight forward way. But if there are no other options tunnelling it is.

Comment: Another option is to encrypt the workload before passing to doHighBackground() and decrypt inside the worker.

Comment: Going through a tunnel is going to be much more efficient though. Without touching the codebase which is costly, requires tests and so on.